# Include calculated value in angular filter results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to apply a filter to a value calculated from a dataset without modifying the actual dataset? For example -

```
<input ng-model="query">

<li ng-repeat='val in values | filter:query'>
  {{val.a}} + {{val.b}}
</li>
```

I would want to search on the result of val.a + val.b

Comment: We can write a custom filter for this. For example have a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.filter('customFilter', function(){
  return function(input){
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      input[i].search = input[i].a + input[i].b;
    }
    return input;
  }
})

<li ng-repeat="name in names | customFilter | filter : {search: query}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6y8h4tw/) to demonstarte the same.Use custom filter to search for the sum of posts and comments by user.

```
myApp.filter('sumofTwo', function() {
 return function(items, search) {
     var temp=[];
    if (!search) {
      return items;
    }

     for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
         console.log(search);
         console.log(items[i].posts+items[i].comments);
         if((items[i].posts+items[i].comments)==search){
         temp.push(items[i]);
         }
     }
  return temp;   
 }
});

 $scope.users = [{
        name: 'Kenny',
        posts: 1,
        comments: 6
    }, {
        name: 'Kyle',
        posts: 2,
        comments: 7
    }, {
        name: 'Eric',
        posts: 3,
        comments: 8
    }, {
        name: 'Stan',
        posts: 4,
        comments: 9
    }, {
        name: 'Butters',
        posts: 5,
        comments: 10
    }, ];
```